# Can't draw shapes over imported image

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

I am working on a new project that relies on Turtle's ability to import images. However, I have found that if I import and draw the image as a shape, nothing else can be drawn on top of it. How should this be adjusted so that Turtle can draw over the image(s)?

```
import turtle

def insert_img(image):
  turtle.Screen().register_shape(str(image))
  turtle.Turtle().shape(str(image))

turtle.speed(0)
insert_img('The Image.png')
turtle.pendown()
turtle.goto(150,-150)
```

**Edit:** I didn't find a direct solution to the issue, but I found a cheaty workaround that works around for me. Using multiple turtles and replacing the cursors with different images allows them to be utilized in a similar fashion to what I'm looking for. If anyone can find a better solution, great! Feel free to share it.

```
import turtle

turtle.Screen().addshape("The Image.png")
the_image = turtle.Turtle()
the_image.shape("The Image.png")

the_image.speed(0)
the_image.pendown()
the_image.goto(150,-150)
```

Comment: My best guess is that you are calling the turtle, then the picture, which means the picture will be over the turtle. You might wan to create a turtle after doing `insert_img`.

Comment: Already tried doing that using turtle = turtle.Turtle(); it only allowed other turtle cursors to be seen, but nothing drawn would show up over above it.

Comment: The solution you came up with is pretty cool